# Works for radio, not for checkbox. Whats wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress

So this is all pretty new to me. Struggling my way through code and all posted here already. Can anyone tell me, why this basic code does show how many time a radiobutton is selected, but when I use it on a checkbox, it will not display how many times that checkbox is selected. Should do that right, also for checkboxes?

```
$args = array(
‘posts_per_page’ => -1, //get all posts
‘post_type’ => ‘project’, //posts, pages, whatever the field is attached to
‘meta_key’ => ‘project_status’, //custom field slug
‘meta_value’ => ‘Finished’ //location to count
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); //get WP Query using $args

$count = $the_query->post_count; //use property post_count to return the count

echo ‘Finished: ‘. $count;
```

Comment: Dont use non ascii simple quotes like this `‘` it messes up the compiler. Normally means you are using a Word Processor to write code, try using a simple editor like VSCode its good and free

Comment: A significant difference between radio and checkbox is, that the value of an unticked checkbox won't be sent with the request. Well, if no radio was selected it would be the same, but once a radio has been selected, it won't be toggled off completely.

Comment: What exactly about the code you have shown us, is supposed to have anything to do with checkboxes or radio buttons? You're querying some posts of type `project` and with a specific status there, but I don't see where this would have anything to do with either checkboxes or radio buttons.